# Error with Sqlite Insert operation: near"s": syntax error unable to execute statement

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I've locate the error in `Insert` operation in DEBUG mode.But I just can't figure out where the error is.
here is my Table schema:

```
QString CreateTable="CREATE TABLE History("
                        "hist_code VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,"
                        "input_data TEXT NOT NULL,"
                        "output_data TEXT NOT NULL)";
QString InsertIntoTable="INSERT INTO History (hist_code,input_data,output_data) "
                        "VALUES (%1,%2,%3);";
```

Then I've successfully created the Table `History`,
but when do Insert Operation.

```
void InsertHistory(const size_t& no_run){
    if(!db.isOpen())
        db.open();
    InputToString input2str(in_temp);
    OutputToString output2str(out_temp);

    QString histcode=QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")+QString::number(no_run,10);
    QString inputdata=input2str.getAll();
    QString outputdata=output2str.getAll();

    if (!query.exec(InsertIntoTable.arg(histcode,inputdata,outputdata)))
            QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Insert Error"),
                                  query.lastError().text());
}
```

The message box just popped up said :near"s": syntax error unable to execute statement...

Comment: what is `InsertIntoTable`?

Comment: It'a a pre-wrote QString for Insert operation.

Comment: is `InsertIntoTable` a function?, I think it's a QString, please show the contents of that variable.

Comment: sooooorry , I've add the contents.